# Combining two bash scripts by adding flags

Tags: bash, shell-script, conversion

I have two scripts which transform the code from `software v.1` to `software v.2` and viceversa. These are essentially a lot of `sed` substitutions.

In the way I wrote them they accept two arguments: first, the input file , and second the output file.

```
$ ./transform2new oldfile newfile
```

or

```
$ ./transform2old newfile oldfile
```

I'd like to merge both codes and manage the transformation with a flag, e.g,

```
$ ./transform -n oldfile newfile
$ ./transform -o newfile oldfile
```

**Question**

How could I write a single script to achieve the purpose?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Put the contents of each script in a function and you are done. Treat these functions as if they were your scripts (you can start the functions with arguments). E.g.

```
function transform2new() {
  # here the code from script one
}

function transform2old() {
  # here the code from script two
}

# here comes the new super script, that reads the arguments and the option:
if [ "$1" = "-n" ]; then
  transform2new "$1" "$2"
elif [ "$1" = "-o" ]; then
  transform2old "$1" "$2"
fi
```

Comment: The parameters for the function calls should be `"$2" "$3"` instead of `"$1" "$2"`.